# Finding all solutions for Bernoulli inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

in our course we have been given the task to find all real solutions to the inequality

$(1+x)^n \geq 1 + nx$ ($\forall n \in \mathbb{N} $).

I have already proved this for $x \geq -1$ using induction and worked out the behavior for $-2 \leq x < -1$.

What I have trouble with is proving the fact, that the inequality does not hold for $ x \leq -2 $. Some other posts I have read about this problem used derivatives, which are not yet in my repertoire...

I hope some of you can point me to the right direction, thanks in advance.

Comment: For $\;x=-2\;,\;\;n=1\;$ it is already false. For some values of $\;n\;$ though the inequality still holds, can you see?

Comment: Ty for your answer, I think I see your point. I corrected my post above, cause the inequality should hold **for all** $n \in \mathbb{N} $

Comment: see the following for your proof:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the case $x \in [-2, 0]$: Now we want to show that $f(x) = (1+x)^n - (1+nx)$ that f is strictly monotonically decreasing on this interval.

Let $y < z$ : 
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(z) - f(y) &= ((1+z)^n - (1+nz)) - ((1+y)^n - (1+ny)) \\
            &= (1+z)^n - (1+y)^n + n(y-z) \\
            &= (z-y)(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+z)^k(1+y)^{n-k} - n) 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

Where
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+z)^k(1+y)^{n-k} < n  $ since $|1+z|, |1+y| \le 1$ but $1+z = 1+y = 1$ not possible under the requirement $y < z$.

It follows, that $f(z) - f(y) < 0 $ $\implies$ strictly monotonically decreasing. Since $f(0)=0$ the Bernoulli-inequality hold for this interval.

Consider the last case $x < -2$: Define a = -2 - x $\implies$ $1+x = -(1+a)$

For odd n you can find:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(1+nx) - (1+x)^n &= (-1)^n ((1+x)^n - (1+nx)) \\
                 &= (1+a)^n - (-1)^n (1-n(a+2)) \\
                 &\ge 1 + na + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}a^2 \\
                 &\ge 1+ na + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}a^2 + 1 - n(a+2) \\
                 &= (n-1)(\frac{n}{2}a^2 - 2) \\
 &= (n-1)\frac{na^2-4}{2} \\
 &> a
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$
for $n > \frac{4}{a^2} = \frac{4}{(x+2)^2}$, so that the inequality does not hold

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want those $x$ so that it holds for all $n$, 
$1+nx\leq (1+x)^n$.

In that case one can show by induction that for $x\leq -2$ that 
$$(1+x)^{2n+1}< 1+(2n+1)x.$$

I would be glad to see your solution for the interval $(-2,-1)$.